# Adding MYSQL to Cloud Foundry and using it as a service

Tags: mysql, service, cloud-foundry

I am new to cloud foundry service, and wondering if the community can help to answer my question.

I have a simple WordPress app pushed to Cloud Foundry `cf push Wordpress` which has backend MYSQL servers. I have been asked to add MYSQL as a service within Cloud Foundry, but currently this does not exist.

When i perform `cf marketplace` there is not an option for MYSQL.

Simply put how do i get MYSQL on Cloud Foundry for my app to use it as a service.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying with pivotal web services or pivotal cloud foundry? If you are using pivotal web services, choose cleardb service that provides mysql db as a service. For pivotal cloud foundry, you need to download p-mysql product from https://network.pivotal.io site and upload the file to pcf ops manager.

Comment: I second Kumaresh's comment.  It depends on how you are deploying CF.  If you're using the open source deployment methods or Bosh Lite, see @dkoper's response below.  If you're using a specific public provider, please indicate which one and someone can point you in the right direction.  Same if you're using a commercial version of CF, as the exact process can differ.

Answer (score 0):

Here are instructions how to deploy a MySQL bosh release to your environment and register a service broker for it so that it appears in `cf marketplace`: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-mysql-release